# Heroku addons:create --fork doesn't migrate redis data

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have an app hosted on Heroku and I am trying to migrate from Heroku Redis to Redis Cloud.

According to this documentation, I can easily migrate the data from my current Heroku Redis to a new Redis Cloud by using --fork flag.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#migrating-from-an-existing-redis-server-to-redis-cloud

However, when I ran the command, it did create a new Redis Cloud instance but the instance doesn't have the data from my Heroku Redis instance.

This is the command that I used to create the instance

```
heroku addons:create rediscloud:100 --fork=`heroku config:get REDIS_URL -a app-name` -a app-name
```

Is the `--fork` flag only works for databases ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, fork will make a copy of the application, it's addons and data contained in Heroku Postgres.

Comment: yep, but I don't want to fork the whole app. I just want to create a new addon ( in this case, `Redis Cloud` ) and fork/migrate the data from `Heroku Redis`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same experience when trying to migrate from Heroku Redis to Redis Cloud: my 'forked' database was empty.

I contacted Redis Labs Support and they said:

> *We currently do not support the `--fork` option to migrate data from
> Heroku Redis to Redis Cloud  ... [but] you can directly import your data
> into your Redis Cloud database by following the steps in [this
> document](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rc/databases/import-data/#import-from-a-redis-server).*

I followed the steps under "Import from a Redis server" using my Heroku Redis host, port and password and was able to populate a Redis Cloud db from an older Heroku Redis instance that was using Redis 5.0.

BUT I could not get the process to work for a more recent Heroku Redis instance on v6.2!

I contacted Redis Labs Support again and this time they said:

> Import from Redis can accept only Open Source Redis URLs and not an
> Heroku (cloud) database. You must export your data to AWS S3, Azure,
> or Google Cloud storage and then import it to the Redis Enterprise
> cloud.

In the end, I managed to copy (Dump and Restore) the contents of my v6.2 Heroku Redis to Redis Cloud using
[nicStuff's redis-migrate gist](https://gist.github.com/nicStuff/ee7feb8eed00174a46db42812545b403) (a slightly modified version)...

BUT I've only managed to get this working from a Heroku Redis Mini plan. Other plans (Premium-0, etc) require TLS and I'm not sure if it's possible to connect to these using redis-cli...